# Why separate authentication is required for imap and smtp?

Tags: python, email, smtp, imap

I am using imaplib and smtplib libraries of python
However I have to separately login to imap and smtp servers like below

imap:

```
self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.imap_server,self.imap_port)
r, d = self.imap.login(self.username, self.password)
```

smtp:

```
self.smtp = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server, self.smtp_port)
self.smtp.ehlo()
self.smtp.starttls()
self.smtp.login(self.username, self.password)
```

Is there be any method which can login to both at a same time?

Comment: They are completely different services and may (theoretically) have different credentials. If you really want to, you can extend built in classes and come up with your own login method that does both.

Comment: These two services can even be placed on difference hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is that neither the IMAP protocol nor the SMTP protocol offer a way to say "you can use the same credentials here as for (some other service)" or anything like that. Such a protocol feature would be possible, perhaps as a [SASL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422) feature, but it's not a simple extension.

It wasn't done in the bronze age because SMTP only started using passwords when spammers and mobile devices came along. Until then, IMAP used passwords but SMTP generally not.

So we're left with lots of people assuming that the two are the same, lots of clients supporting only that case, but the client libraries work as if IMAP and SMTP were different worlds.